# Getting CSS class contents from among multiple stylesheets via JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JS library using canvas that needs to get its colors from CSS classes. The classes used by the library are predetermined, but which stylesheet (out of possibly many) is not.

With a class like this:

```
.a_preset_class {
    margin: 10pt;
    color: rgba(216,34,21,0.5);
}
```

I would like to be able to write something like this:

`context.strokeStyle = getClassColor("a_preset_class");`

and have `context.strokeStyle` be set to `"rgba(216,34,21,0.5);"`

The obvious way is to traverse `document.styleSheets`, but I'm hoping there's a less drastic way that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to use Dojo in your site, you can use dojox.data.CssRuleStore to make a searchable store of all of your CSS rules. You then use the standard fetch() method to search the store, using the style rule's "selector" property as your search term. E.g.,

```
ruleStore = dojox.data.CssRuleStore(); // make it a global if it's not part of a widget
                                       // so that it's accessible by the other methods
                                       // below when calling ruleStore.getValue()
var rulesFound = [];

// When querying the store, you can either do an exact match search such as ".myClass",
// or do a wildcard-based search such as ".myClass*" (find all rules that start with
// ".myClass", "*.myClass*" (all rules containing ".myClass" somewhere in the selector),
// "?someValue" (any rules that have an arbitrary first character, followed by
// "someRule"), etc.
var queryObj = {"selector": ".a_preset_class"};

var checkEmpty = function(count, request) {
    if (count < 1)
        // do your empty response logic here
};

var processRule = function(item, request) {
    rulesFound.push(ruleStore.getValue(item, "style"); // Add the item's CSSStyleDeclaration object with all assigned values to the results array
};

ruleStore.fetch({query: queryObj, onBegin: checkEmpty, onItem: processRule});
```

Using this code as a starting point, you could create a function that takes the desired search term as its parameter, passes that in to the query, and then returns the array of CSS rules that were found. Then you can just iterate the response array after calling the function, and make whatever changes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var who= document.createElement('span');
who.className="a_preset_class";
var css= document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(who,'').getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

Comment: This is faster than traversing, but you can't tell if the class is missing as the default style for the element will be applied to it. Also, you need to add the element to the page to get the class to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that you can reuse...

```
function testrules(findrule)
{
 var myrules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;

 for (var i=0; i<myrules.length.length; i++)
 {
  if (myrules[i].selectorText==findrule) {alert('document.styleSheets[0].cssRules['+i+'] = '+myrules[i].cssText); break;}
 }
}
```

Call the function as so...

```
<div><a href="javascript:testrules('a:hover');">what is a:hover?</a></div>
```

With some modification you can have it return a value or '0' if no matching rule was met. You could also have it iterate through multiple style sheets easily as well with a second for loop.

Comment: This is what I mean by traversing `document.styleSheets`; it's the method I'm hoping to avoid. Also, I can't rely on the classes being in `document.styleSheets[0]`.